# how to access global variable based on drop down event change using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access global variable from function, i want to call variable outside from inside function variable.This is what I tried. Note: the query function should be work after click on query function from html drop down selection. Thank you for helping

```
HTML 

<select  name="myInput" id="choice1">
       <li><option value="6011">apib_cadastral:bivel</option></li>
       <li><option value="6012">apib_cadastral:burhchaura</option></li>
 </select>
```

```
Javascript
var layer_name;
function query() {
  var text_value = document.getElementsByName('myInput')[0];
  layer_name = text_value.options[text_value.selectedIndex].text;
}
query();
var owsrootUrl ='http://127.0.0.1:8020/geoserver/apib_cadastral/ows';
    var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: layer_name,
            outputFormat: 'application/json',
            format_options: 'callback:getJson'
   };
   var callbackstring=defaultParameters.format_options;
   var cbstring=callbackstring.slice(9,27);
   var parametres = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
   var geoserver_ur = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parametres);
var config = {
geojson: geoserver_ur
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `config.geojson = layer_name` inside the `query()` function only at the end.

Comment: could please add some sample code

Comment: `config.geojson = layer_name` just add this inside `query()` function... after `layer_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `var config = ....` inside `query` function. Also you should call `query()` onchange of dropdown

Try this:

```js
var layer_name;
var config = {};
function query() {
  var text_value = document.getElementsByName('myInput')[0];
  layer_name = text_value.options[text_value.selectedIndex].text;
  config = {
   geojson: layer_name,
  };
  console.log(config)
}
query();
```

```html
<select onchange="query()" name="myInput" id="choice1">
  <li>
   <option value="6011">apib_cadastral:bivel</option>
  </li>
  <li>
   <option value="6012">apib_cadastral:burhchaura</option>
  </li>
</select>
```

Comment: I want to get layer_name out of function

Comment: I want to call back layer_name into config variable

Comment: I have updated code please check once,help me that way,thank you for helping